# Fill np.nan condition within for/if-else loop

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I have been working on this for a while and just can't seem to find the answer to what I need.  Suppose I have a dataframe as below.

What I would like to do is fill the last three rows of `df['gender']` based on the value in `df['home_work']` column, specifically if `home_work` > 9, then `m`, if not, then `f`.  Please keep in mind this is just a **made up dataset** and I don't mean to offend anyone, I promise!

```rb
enr = pd.DataFrame({'name_id':[1254, 1359, 1254, 1296, 1353, 2656], 
                   'enrollment_term':['spring 2018', 'spring 2018', 'fall 2018', 'spring 2018', 'spring 2018', 'fall 2020'],
                   'gpa_term': [2.93, np.nan, 1.65, 4.00, 3.95, 2.92],
                   'dog_owner':[0,1,1,1, 1, 0],
                   'salary':[50657, 90658, np.nan, 104352, np.nan, 102043],
                   'home_work':[34, np.nan, 12, 9, 8, 27],
                   'gender':['m','f','f',np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

enr
```

Below is the code that I attempted but it presented the error down below:

```rb
for i in df['gender'].isna():
    if df['home_work'][i] > 9:
        df['gender'][i].fillna('m')
    else:
        df['gender'][i].fillna('f')
```

```rb
KeyError: False
```

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated as I have been working on this for a while.  I have a dataset of 90K + that I want to adapt this work to and would like to create a function that streamlines this process but have hit a speedbump!

The issue I am running into is that `np.nan` defaults and fills in a value for `gender` if it doesn't meet the requirement.  Thoughts?

---

### # Edited

Suppose I have the following df:

```rb
enr = pd.DataFrame({'name_id':[1254, 1359, 1254, 1296, 1353, 2656], 
                   'enrollment_term':['spring 2018', 'spring 2018', 'fall 2018', 'spring 2018', 'spring 2018', 'fall 2020'],
                   'gpa_term': [2.93, np.nan, 1.65, 4.00, 3.95, 2.92],
                   'dog_owner':[0,1,1,1, 1, 0],
                   'salary':[50657, 90658, np.nan, 104352, np.nan, 102043],
                   'home_work':[np.nan, np.nan, 0.7, 0.3, 0.64, 0.49],
                   'gender':[0, 1, 1,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

[image]

I would like to impute `enr['gender']` based on `home_work`.  If `enr['home_work'] >= 0.5`, then `enr['gender'] == 0`, else **(as long as `enr['home_work'] != np.nan`)**, `enr['gender'] == 1`.

What I don't want is imputation of values in `enr[gender]` where their `enr['home_work']` is `np.nan`I have tried many different techniques but all seem to impute a 1.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
enr['gender'] = np.where(enr['home_work'] > 9,  
                         enr['gender'].fillna('m'),
                         enr['gender'].fillna('f'))
```

Or filter separately by 2 masks:

```
m = enr['gender'].isna()
enr.loc[m, 'gender'] = np.where(enr['home_work'] > 9,  'm',  'f')[m]
```

---

```
print (enr)
   name_id enrollment_term  gpa_term  dog_owner    salary  home_work gender
0     1254     spring 2018      2.93          0   50657.0         34      m
1     1359     spring 2018       NaN          1   90658.0         42      f
2     1254       fall 2018      1.65          1       NaN         12      f
3     1296     spring 2018      4.00          1  104352.0          9      f
4     1353     spring 2018      3.95          1       NaN          8      f
5     2656       fall 2020      2.92          0  102043.0         27      m
```

EDIT:

```
m = enr['gender'].isna() & enr['home_work'].notna()
enr.loc[m, 'gender'] = np.where(enr['home_work'] >= 0.5, 0, 1)[m]
print (enr)
   name_id enrollment_term  gpa_term  dog_owner    salary  home_work  gender
0     1254     spring 2018      2.93          0   50657.0        NaN     0.0
1     1359     spring 2018       NaN          1   90658.0        NaN     1.0
2     1254       fall 2018      1.65          1       NaN       0.70     1.0
3     1296     spring 2018      4.00          1  104352.0       0.30     1.0
4     1353     spring 2018      3.95          1       NaN       0.64     0.0
5     2656       fall 2020      2.92          0  102043.0       0.49     1.0
```

Comment: thank you, I'll try it out.  I ran into issues with `np.where` but I also don't fully grasp it either!  Back to the books!

Comment: Hi Sir, still not sleep yet? :-)

Comment: @jezrael got u ~

Comment: I appreciate your effort here but in my actual dataset, your `np.where` technique defaults to imputing the column when I want it to remain `np.nan`.  Thus it removes all `np.nan` values when I want them to remain and ONLY impute if `enr[salary]` is not null.  Thoughts?

Comment: @TheMattdavis17 - Can you test `m = enr['gender'].isna() & enr['salary'].notna()
enr.loc[m, 'gender'] = np.where(enr['home_work'] > 9,  'm',  'f')[m]` ? It is changed second solution

Comment: One adjustment to the sample data above is that in my actual dataset I would like to choose **1** or **0** (binary) based on another column where the threshold for choosing is as follows:  `if df[prev_col] >= 0.5 then df[change_col] == 0` and contrarily, `if df[prev_col] < 0.5, then df[change_col] == 1`.

Comment: The issue that I am running into seems to be with the difference from the previous col being a `float64` and the `change_col` being `int64`.  Does this make sense?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @TheMattdavis17 - It seems need new column add to DataFrame, can you ediit question how looks new column? What data are in column?

Comment: OK, just a moment.

Comment: Genius!  Thank you for your help in working through this.  I need to up my game with `np.where` but you have really helped me answer this issue.

Comment: @TheMattdavis17 - Maybe you can create new question, not sure if I will be offline in few minures, 30-40 minutes

Comment: I appreciate it.  I'll do just this.

Answer (score 3):

Let us try `map` the value and `where`

```
df.gender=df.gender.where(df.gender.notna(),df.home_work.gt(9).map({True:'m',False:'f'})) 


df
   name_id enrollment_term  gpa_term  dog_owner    salary  home_work gender
0     1254     spring 2018      2.93          0   50657.0       34.0      m
1     1359     spring 2018       NaN          1   90658.0        NaN      f
2     1254       fall 2018      1.65          1       NaN       12.0      f
3     1296     spring 2018      4.00          1  104352.0        9.0      f
4     1353     spring 2018      3.95          1       NaN        8.0      f
5     2656       fall 2020      2.92          0  102043.0       27.0      m
```